# Thread safety problems trying to databind across threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, data-binding, datagrid, thread-safety

I have a form with a datagrids that is bound to a bindinglist of Data that is being populated by a constant stream of data from a tcpip connection. The TCPIP connection is on a thread that should constatly loop and when it finds enough data create an instance of the class Data and add it to the BindingList(of Data). I am getting an error that says "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.". The stack trace points to the line that adds new data to the bindinglist(of Data)

```
DataList.Insert(0, dataItem)
```

What is strange to me is it then keeps going on and populates my datagrid properly. I am not very experienced with multithreaded programming and most of my code has always been asynchronous. I have a datalock and some mutexes(something I just learned about but am not sure I am using correctly). I read somewhere that using events would help but if the NewData event isn't necessary I can get rid of it. Any help in making my code thread safe would be greatly appreciated.

The binding on the form is like this:

```
myDataGrid.datasource = myDataReader.DataList
```

Here is the class launching the tread and reading the data(sorry I know it's a lot of code but I didn't want to leave something out that could be important):

```
Public Class DataReader
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
#Region "Properties"
Dim dataMutex As Mutex
Dim UnparsedMutex As Mutex
Dim mIP_Address As String
Dim convertingData As Boolean = False
Public Property IP_Address() As String
    Get
        Return mIP_Address
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mIP_Address = value
    End Set
End Property
Dim mPort As Integer
Public Property Port As Integer
    Get
        Return mPort
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        mPort = value
    End Set
End Property
Private WithEvents mDataList As BindingList(Of Data)
Public ReadOnly Property DataList As BindingList(Of Data)
    Get
        Return mDataList
    End Get
End Property
Public Event valueChanged As Eventhandler
Private Event NewDataAvaiable(ByVal newData As BindingList(Of Data))
Private mUnparsedData As String = ""
Private Property UnParsedData As String
    Get
        Return mUnparsedData
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mUnparsedData = value
    End Set
End Property
#End Region
#Region "Private Variables"
Dim mTCPIPClient As TcpClient
Dim mConnected As Boolean
Dim mTCPIPStream As NetworkStream
Dim mLastError As String
Dim mDataThread As System.Threading.Thread
Private dataLock As New Object
#End Region
#Region "Constructors"
Public Sub New(ByVal IPAddress As String, ByVal Port As Integer)
    dataMutex = New Mutex(False, "MUTEXDATA")
    UnparsedMutex = New Mutex(False, "MUTEXUNPARSEDDATA")
    mIP_Address = IPAddress
    mPort = Port
    mConnected = False
    mDataList = New BindingList(Of Data)
    DataList.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Events"
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Methods"
Public Sub ConnectTCPIP()
    Try
        If Not mTCPIPClient Is Nothing AndAlso mTCPIPClient.Connected Then
            mLastError = "Connection Error:Already connected"
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(mIP_Address) Then
            mLastError = "Connection Error:No IP Address"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DataList.Clear()
        UnParsedData = String.Empty

        mTCPIPClient = New TcpClient()
        mTCPIPClient.Connect(mIP_Address, mPort)
        If mTCPIPClient.Connected Then
            mTCPIPClient.ReceiveTimeout = 500
            mTCPIPClient.SendTimeout = 500
            mTCPIPClient.LingerState = New System.Net.Sockets.LingerOption(False, 0)
            mTCPIPClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 100000
            mTCPIPClient.SendBufferSize = 100000
            mTCPIPStream = mTCPIPClient.GetStream
            LaunchDataThread()
            If mDataThread.IsAlive Then mConnected = True
        Else
            mLastError = "Connection Error:Unknown Reason"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
Public Sub Disconnect()
    DisconnectTCPIP()
    KillDataThread()
End Sub
Private Sub DisconnectTCPIP()
    If Not mTCPIPClient Is Nothing AndAlso mTCPIPClient.Connected Then
        mTCPIPClient.Close()
        mTCPIPClient = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
Public Function IsConnected() As Boolean
    If mTCPIPClient Is Nothing OrElse mDataThread Is Nothing Then Return False
    Return mTCPIPClient.Connected AndAlso mDataThread.IsAlive
End Function
Public Sub LaunchDataThread()
    mDataThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ReadData)
    mDataThread.Start()
End Sub
Public Sub KillDataThread()
    If Not mDataThread Is Nothing AndAlso mDataThread.IsAlive() Then
        mDataThread.Abort()
    End If
    mDataThread = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub ReadData()
    Try
        While True
            Dim count As Short = 0
            While Not mTCPIPClient.Connected AndAlso count <= 5
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                ConnectTCPIP()
                count += 1
            End While

            If mTCPIPClient.Connected = False Then Exit Sub
            Dim dataBuffer(500) As Byte
            Dim readBytes As Integer = 0
            UnparsedMutex.WaitOne()
            Do While mTCPIPStream.DataAvailable
                readBytes = mTCPIPStream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, 500)
                UnParsedData += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuffer.Take(readBytes).ToArray())
            Loop
            UnparsedMutex.ReleaseMutex()
            If UnParsedData.Length > 0 Then ProcessNewData()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
Public Sub ProcessNewData()
    Dim dataToProcess As String = ""
    UnparsedMutex.WaitOne()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(UnParsedData) Then
        UnparsedMutex.ReleaseMutex()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    dataToProcess = UnParsedData.Substring(0, UnParsedData.LastIndexOf("PLC") + 3)
    UnParsedData = UnParsedData.Remove(0, dataToProcess.Length)
    UnparsedMutex.ReleaseMutex()
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataToProcess) Then
        Dim matches = dataToProcess.Split(";"c)

        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            Dim newData As New BindingList(Of Data)
            Try
                For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
                    newData.Insert(0, New Data(matches(i).Value))
                Next
                RaiseEvent NewDataAvaiable(newData)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace)
            End Try
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub OnNewData(ByVal newData As BindingList(Of Data)) Handles Me.NewDataAvaiable
    SyncLock dataLock
        dataMutex.WaitOne()
        For Each dataItem As Data In newData
            DataList.Insert(0, dataItem)
            If DataList.Count > 5000 Then DataList.RemoveAt(5000)
        Next
        dataMutex.ReleaseMutex()
    End SyncLock
End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

**UPDATE**: the bindingList(of Data) would never need to be updated from the UI so the only thread changing the data should be the mDatathread in the DataReader class.

Comment: Any suggestions or even guesses would be greatly appreciated I need to get this going!

Answer (score 0):

Look into InvokeRequired, Invoke, Delegate.

Example here, I have a UDP server in background thread(background worker) receiving MessageEntries and Listview1 in main thread. This is a legacy winforms project on NET4.0

The following is called from background thread:

```
Delegate Sub SetListViewCallback(ByVal NewMsg As MessageEntry)

Private Sub addItemToListView(ByVal NewMsg As MessageEntry)
    Dim item1 As New ListViewItem(NewMsg.Time.ToString(), 0)
    item1.SubItems.Add(NewMsg.IP.ToString())
    If ListView1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetListViewCallback(AddressOf addItemToListView)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {NewMsg})
    Else
        ListView1.Items.Add(item1)
    End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: I just checked this method with a BindedList as a Datasource for DataGridView and it still works. Only difference is that the conditional if checks if DataGridView object requires Invoke and in the Else section you put the modification of BindedList.